# Adding point geometries to shapefile in GDAL (C#)

Tags: c#, shapefile, gdal, qgis

I am trying to make shapefiles with point geometries using GDAL. I am following the example given [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/createdata.cs). I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and the programming language is C#. For now, I am just making one point at the origin and I'm viewing the resulting shapefiles in QGIS. For some reason, I am not being able to view the point which I make. I have tried making a polygon too but I am facing the same problem. Below is the code I have written:

```
        public void testSF(Dataset ds)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing ERSI shapefile");
        // Registering drivers
        OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();
        OSGeo.OGR.Driver driverSH = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");

        if (driverSH == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot get drivers. Exiting");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Drivers fetched");

        // Creating a shapefile
        OSGeo.OGR.DataSource dataSourceSH = driverSH.CreateDataSource("ERSI_TEST_ShapeFile.shp", new string[] { });
        if (dataSourceSH == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot create datasource");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Shapefile created");

        // Creating a point layer
        OSGeo.OGR.Layer layerSH;
        layerSH = dataSourceSH.CreateLayer("PolygonLayer", null, OSGeo.OGR.wkbGeometryType.wkbPoint, new string[] { });
        if (layerSH == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Layer creation failed, exiting...");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Polygon Layer created");

        // Creating and adding attribute fields to layer
        OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn fdefnName = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("Name", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
        fdefnName.SetWidth(32);

        OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn fdefnGPS = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("GPS", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
        fdefnGPS.SetWidth(32);

        if (layerSH.CreateField(fdefnName, 1) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Name field failed");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        if (layerSH.CreateField(fdefnGPS, 1) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating GPS field failed");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Fields created and added to layer");
        OSGeo.OGR.Feature featureSH = new OSGeo.OGR.Feature(layerSH.GetLayerDefn());
        featureSH.SetField("Name", "This is a NAME");
        featureSH.SetField("GPS", "Test GPS point");

        // Outer Ring 
        // Methodology: Create a linear ring geometry, add it to a polygon geometry. Add polygon geometry to feature. Add feature to layer

        OSGeo.OGR.Feature feature = new OSGeo.OGR.Feature( layerSH.GetLayerDefn() );
        OSGeo.OGR.Geometry geom = OSGeo.OGR.Geometry.CreateFromWkt("POINT(0.0 0.0)");

        feature.SetGeometry(geom);
        layerSH.CreateFeature(feature);
}
```

This code adds a point to the polygon layer at 0.0 and 0.0. However, when I open the resulting layer in QGIS, I can not see/locate the point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with last GDAL release and it works.

You have to close the datasource (call Dispose method) to update the file with the created geometry otherwise you will just view an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are missing to define the spatial reference